# How to PEP8 a long array of strings with comments

Tags: python, django, pep8

The line with a comment is wider than 80 characters:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'mydogslow.middleware.MyWatchdogMiddleware',
    'gattlib.djangomiddleware.SetRemoteAddrFromXRealIP',
    'i18n.middleware.SetLanguageMiddleware',
    'whitelabels.middleware.SetWhitelabelMiddleware', # after SetLanguageMiddleware
    'myaffiliateprogram.middleware.BlockReferringURLs',
)
```

The most natural way I can break it up is this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'mydogslow.middleware.MyWatchdogMiddleware',
    'gattlib.djangomiddleware.SetRemoteAddrFromXRealIP',
    'i18n.middleware.SetLanguageMiddleware',
    'whitelabels.middleware.'
        'SetWhitelabelMiddleware', # after SetLanguageMiddleware
    'myaffiliateprogram.middleware.BlockReferringURLs',
)
```

Unfortunately, the hanging indent violates PEP8.

Thanks in advance for showing me how you would break this line up.

Comment: Note that is a tuple, not an array.

Comment: when in doubt, use the [pep8 style guide checker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8), it usually produces good results. It doesn't like the indentation in you second example, and complains about not having at least two spaces between code and comments.

Comment: mata I'm using the PEP8 checker that's built into PyCharm. I'm trying to find a solution that makes it not error prone when another developer comes later and copies/pastes lines to move things around. The indent solution I posted accomplishes this, but doesn't pass PEP8.

Answer (score 9):

I would just move the comment:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'mydogslow.middleware.MyWatchdogMiddleware',
    'gattlib.djangomiddleware.SetRemoteAddrFromXRealIP',
    'i18n.middleware.SetLanguageMiddleware',
    # This middleware needs to be after SetLanguageMiddleware
    'whitelabels.middleware.SetWhitelabelMiddleware',
    'myaffiliateprogram.middleware.BlockReferringURLs',
)
```

Comment: This works. but I'm not a fan of seeing the code on 2 lines. My concern is that those 2 lines get copied/pasted separately and won't be paired together, unless we visually connect them somehow. Perhaps a blank line above the comment and below the SetWhitelabelMiddleware.

Comment: I agree - if you're concerned about that happening, adding a blank line on either side would help make it clear that those two lines are related.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your answer is gonna be the final winner. I'm gonna wait a day or two before selecting it just in case someone suggests a new idea.